# What's the dimension of a Lie algebra generated by transpositions on $n$ objects?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, lie-algebras, catalan-numbers

Define a Lie bracket on the group algebra of the permutation group $S_n$ in the following way:
$$[\sigma, \tau] = \sigma\circ\tau - \tau\circ\sigma,$$
where $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$, and the multiplication on permutations is defined as composition. My question is, what is the dimension of the Lie subalgebra generated by transpositions, i.e. $(ij)$? My conjecture is that the dimension is given by $C_n - \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, where $C_n$ is the Catalan number. Is this correct and what is the proof?

For example, when $n=3$, using the cycle notation, we have
$$
[(12),(23)] = (132) - (123) \\
[(23),(31)] = (132) - (123) \\
[(31),(12)] = (132) - (123) \\
$$
and
$$
[(12), (132) - (123)] = 2((23) - (13)), \text{etc.}
$$
Therefore this algebra is $4 = C_3 - 1$ dimensional.

Comment: You've only defined the Lie bracket on transpositions but the output of the Lie bracket won't be a sum of transpositions in general so what is the definition of the Lie bracket on a more general permutation? Are you taking the Lie subalgebra of [the group algebra of $S_n$ under commutator] generated by transpositions?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That's how I interpreted the OP's question: what's the Lie subalgebra of $\Bbb C S_n$ generated by the transpositions?

Comment: What data do you have to support the conjecture? (I quite like it and wish I had time at the moment to play with it properly.)

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I have numerically check this up to n=6. The intuition of this conjecture comes from the Schur-Weyl duality.

Comment: Could you expand on that intuition?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I could prove that this algebra can be faithfully represented by the centralizer of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ represented on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$. The dimension of this centralizer is $C_n$. My conjecture is that this algebra is actually the same as this centralizer except for some center elements.

Comment: Considering $\Bbb CS_n\to\bigoplus{\rm End}(M_\lambda)$, we could ask the dimension of the lie subalgebra of ${\frak gl}(M_\lambda)$ which is generated for a partition $\lambda$. Or, we could ask the same question of other groups and generating sets, especially other Coxeter groups.

Comment: I think this post is more appropriate for [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: @C.F.G Thanks for the suggestion. I will do that.